# must have washed downstream VS must have been washed downstream

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tenses, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

There are two hikers hiking near a stream. One of them seeing it in says:

Look! A miner's old pack and gear! Must have washed downstream!

My question is:

Is it just a simple passive voice sentence with omitted auxiliary "to be"?

Like: Must have washed downstream! = Must have been washed downstream!

Thank you!

Comment: "Wash" in this sense seems to work equally well in the active or passive, and for as long as I can remember it has always done so. It is not one of those jarring neologisms of grammar which people of a certain age, like me, reject.

Comment: Have a look at what’s called [_unaccusative verbs_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb) – that should give you a better idea of what’s going on here. If something remains unclear after that, you can edit your question to include what you now understand, and what still isn’t clear to you.

Comment: Thank you @WS2 for giving me a hint.

Comment: Thank you @JanusBahsJacquet I haven't come across this part of English grammar and never heard before of "unaccusative verbs". I will definitely stay with that subject for a while studying it. After I'm done I'll edit my question just to be sure I learned the subject and understand that relation between subject-verb-object. Thank you